# Neo4j : propagate label through two types of nodes

Tags: neo4j, graph-algorithm

I would like to apply label propagation to my data in Neo4j. My data looks like the image.

[image]

The relationship 'Appears_in' has the weight property and some articles nodes has seed label property.

I would like to propagate this seed labels to create clusters with the articles that speaks about the same topic, for example (politics cluster). More precisely I would like to propagate seed label to another article node but articles do not have a direct relationship between them. They are 'somewhere' connected through the words that they have in commun...

Is it possible to propagate the label from one article node to another article node through the words' node?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is quite a frequent scenario. You want to project a bipartite graph to a monopartite graph. I wrote a [blog post about a very similar scenario](https://towardsdatascience.com/nlp-and-graphs-go-hand-in-hand-with-neo4j-and-apoc-e57f59f46845).

[image: bipartite projection]

I will give you a solution that handles all in one step. It consists of two parts. We project a bipartite graph to a monopartite with the [cypher projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/management-ops/cypher-projection/). In the next step, you run the Label Propagation algorithm. You will be needing the [Neo4j Graph Data Science library](https://github.com/neo4j/graph-data-science). Here is an example query:

```
CALL gds.labelPropagation.write({
nodeQuery:"MATCH (n:Article) RETURN id(n) as id, n.seed_property as seed",
relationshipQuery:"MATCH (a:Article)<-[:APPEARS_IN]-()-[:APPEARS_IN]->(b:Article)
                   RETURN id(a) as source, id(b) as target",
seedProperty: "seed",
writeProperty: "lpa"
})
```

I didn't include the relationship weights as I don't know exactly how you want them handled. You could also use any of the [similarity algorithms](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/similarity/) instead to project a monopartite graph.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much Tomaž. I'm going to try it